# d3js v7, the circle moves in the opposite direction in y coordinate when I drag the circle by the cursor

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to move a circle by dragging it in d3js, but I can't get it to move in the y-axis direction.

I am using v7 of d3js and from several attempts I have found that the `event.x` and `event.y` in the drag function are the coordinates on the graph of the cursor being dragged. Therefore, I tried to transform these two coordinates with the scale transformation function to obtain the coordinates of the display on the svg.

There are two problems here.
The first is that the y-coordinates obtained by `event.y` are the opposite of the actual vertical movement. For example, if I actually run the code and drag the circle to the upper right, the circle will move to the lower right. This is a line symmetry-like movement in the y-coordinate of the circle's initial position; the positive and negative values of the y-coordinate movement are reversed. This is also true for `event.dy`. The x-coordinates in `event.x` and `event.dx` are working fine. Also, `d3.pointer(event)` does not work as intended.

The second problem is that the circle jumps at the beginning of the drag. I found the cause of this by looking within the function that is executed during the drag. The initial values of `event.x` and `event.y` are the initial values of the circle's coordinates, even after multiple drags, which causes the circle to always start moving from the initial value of the circle when it is dragged.

I have [a program that reproduces the problem](https://codepen.io/sankai0044/pen/OJzQrVr?editors=1111).
How can these problems be resolved?

Thanks.
Here is the code.

```js
  var dataset = [
      {x: 5, y: 20, name: "one"},
      {x: 100, y: 33, name: "two"},
      {x: 250, y: 50, name: "three"},
      {x: 480, y: 90, name: "four"},
    ];

  const width = 400;
  const height = 300;
  const margin = { "top": 30, "bottom": 60, "right": 30, "left": 60 };
  const svgWidth = width + margin.left + margin.right;
  const svgHeight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("#graph-area").append("svg")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight)
      .style("border-radius", "20px 20px 20px 20px")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.x; }) + 10])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.y; }) + 10])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var axisx = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
  var axisy = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

  var x = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
    .call(axisx)
    .attr("class", "x_axis")

   x.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width - margin.left - margin.right) / 2 + margin.left)
        .attr("y", 35)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "10pt")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text("X Label")
        .attr("class", "x_axis")

  var y = svg.append("g")
    .call(axisy)
    .attr("class", "y_axis")

  y.append("text")
    .attr("x", -(height - margin.top - margin.bottom) / 2 - margin.top)
    .attr("y", -35)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("font-size", "10pt")
    .text("Y Label")
    .attr("class", "y_axis")

  var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", width )
            .attr("height", height )
            .attr("x", 0) 
            .attr("y", 0);

 
  var circle = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "scatterplot")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  
  circle.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on('mouseover',function(elem, data) {
        //console.log("over data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on('mouseout',function (elem, data) {
        //console.log("out data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on("mousedown", function(elem, data){
        console.log("down data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on("mouseup", function(elem, data){
        console.log("up data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on("drag", circleDragged).on("start", circleStartDrag))

    function circleStartDrag(event){
        console.log("start drag");
    }

    function circleDragged(event){
        d3.select(this).attr('cx', xScale(event.x)).attr('cy', yScale(event.y));
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Scatter Plot</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="graph-area" stype="position: relative;"></div
  
</body>

</html>
```

### Edit (Perception of coordinate calculation in the drag function)

The `drag` function refers to the values set in the data (`cx` and `cy`) and indicates the new coordinates of the cursor reflecting `dy` and `dx` from those values. So in my case I have the unscaled data values set as `event.subject`, so when I drag directly above, it will be calculated as `(cx=250, cy=-40)` based on `(cx=250, cy=-50)` and `dy=-1`. This is then reflected in `event.y`. This is the reason why the y-coordinates of the circle I was talking about during the drag were upside down.

The correct value is set as `(cx=204, cy=150)` as a scaled value of the data at the time of `enter()` execution. When the circle is dragged directly up, `event.y` is set to `cy=140` based on `dy=-1`. In pixel coordinates in svg, a decrease in the y coordinate value means an upward movement, so the circle moves up. At this point I need to update `d.x=event.y` to take into account the reference to the value of `event.subject` in the next drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected result given your code.

You initially position the data points with `scale(d.y)` which converts your data vales to pixel values. When you drag you take the pixel value (event.y) and apply the scale again - scaling pixel values as though they were data.

The data value of d.y = 0 is mapped to `height` by the scale. If you drag a circle that is at the top of the SVG (y=0) then the scale will return `height` which is at the bottom of the SVG - hence your inversion.

The solution is to just use the event.y / event.x values as these values represent pixel values already - there is no need to scale them. If you want to convert the pixel values to data values, then you can use scale.invert() - but this is only useful in updating the data, not the pixel coordinates of each circle.

Removing the scaling functions from the drag reveals one last issue - while the drag moves along with the mouse, you still have a jump on drag start: the drag subject (reference coordinates of the thing being dragged) is by default the x,y properties of your datum. As this represents the data values in your datum, rather than scaled pixel values, you get a jump. The quickest solution would be to redefine the x,y properties of the datum as the scaled pixel values and update these on drag.

```js
var dataset = [
      {x: 5, y: 20, name: "one"},
      {x: 100, y: 33, name: "two"},
      {x: 250, y: 50, name: "three"},
      {x: 480, y: 90, name: "four"},
    ];

  const width = 400;
  const height = 300;
  const margin = { "top": 30, "bottom": 60, "right": 30, "left": 60 };
  const svgWidth = width + margin.left + margin.right;
  const svgHeight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("#graph-area").append("svg")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight)
      .style("border-radius", "20px 20px 20px 20px")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.x; }) + 10])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.y; }) + 10])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var axisx = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
  var axisy = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

  var x = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
    .call(axisx)
    .attr("class", "x_axis")

   x.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width - margin.left - margin.right) / 2 + margin.left)
        .attr("y", 35)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "10pt")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text("X Label")
        .attr("class", "x_axis")

  var y = svg.append("g")
    .call(axisy)
    .attr("class", "y_axis")

  y.append("text")
    .attr("x", -(height - margin.top - margin.bottom) / 2 - margin.top)
    .attr("y", -35)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("font-size", "10pt")
    .text("Y Label")
    .attr("class", "y_axis")

  var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", width )
            .attr("height", height )
            .attr("x", 0) 
            .attr("y", 0);

 
  var circle = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "scatterplot")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  
  circle.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = xScale(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = yScale(d.y); })
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on('mouseover',function(elem, data) {
        //console.log("over data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on('mouseout',function (elem, data) {
        //console.log("out data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on("mousedown", function(elem, data){
        console.log("down data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .on("mouseup", function(elem, data){
        console.log("up data name: " + data.name);
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on("drag", circleDragged).on("start", circleStartDrag))

    function circleStartDrag(event){
        console.log("start drag");
    }

    function circleDragged(event){
        d3.select(this).attr('cx', d=>d.x=event.x).attr('cy', d=>d.y=event.y);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Scatter Plot</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="graph-area" stype="position: relative;"></div
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. I wrote my reply in the answer section because it is too long for the comments section.

Comment: @ymantan, "As far as I know, event.x and event.y are unscale transformed data values": no they are pixel values. I've updated my answer with a snippet and to account for the drag subject to provide a working example.

Comment: Thank you.

Your posting of the code snippet was very helpful. The code worked fine in my environment.

As a confirmation, I have updated my question and written how the `event.x` and `event.y` of the drag function are calculated, so I would be glad if you could correct me if I have made any mistakes in my perception.